# how to load and show inmobi interstitial ads

Tags: android, inmobi

I am new in InMobi I would to display interstitial  ads in android studio then  follow this 
https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/android-guidelines/interstitial-ads-for-android/
but can't understand exactly how to integrate it into the activity where the lines inside activity ?

someone give exemple 
I'm want to integtrate in exist project

```js
InMobiInterstitial interstitialAd = new InMobiInterstitial(InterstitialAdsActivity.this, 1471550843414L, mInterstitialAdListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Setting up an Interstitial Ad

1. To display an Interstitial ad, you need a interstitial placement ID.
2. After adding your app, select INTERSTITIAL AD to create a placement for ad type Interstitial.
3. Once you successfully create the placement, the placement ID is available.

## Adding an Interstitial Ad to your App

Add the following code inside your activity's oncreate() method:

```
InMobiInterstitial interstitial = new InMobiInterstitial(this, placement_id, new InMobiInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener2() {
        @Override
        public void onAdRewardActionCompleted(InMobiInterstitial ad, Map rewards) {}
        @Override
        public void onAdDisplayed(InMobiInterstitial ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdDisplayed: ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdDismissed(InMobiInterstitial ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdDismissed: ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdInteraction(InMobiInterstitial ad, Map params) {}
        @Override
        public void onAdLoadSucceeded(final InMobiInterstitial ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoadSucceeded: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdDisplayFailed(InMobiInterstitial inMobiInterstitial) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdDisplayFailed: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdWillDisplay(InMobiInterstitial inMobiInterstitial) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdWillDisplay: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoadFailed(InMobiInterstitial ad, InMobiAdRequestStatus requestStatus) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoadFailed: " + requestStatus.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdReceived(InMobiInterstitial inMobiInterstitial) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAdReceived: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserLeftApplication(InMobiInterstitial ad){
            Log.d(TAG, "onUserLeftApplication: ");
        }
    });
    interstitial.load();
    if(interstitial.isReady())
        interstitial.show();
```